# NumberPad restrict numeric input

Tags: iphone, cocoa

I have  some simple UITextFields that bring up the Numberpad.

I would like to restrict the control the user has over input.

For example, one particular textField should not been allowed any value over 32.

Which parameter do I use with <32 to enable this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would implement this UITextFieldDelegate method:

```
- (BOOL) textField: (UITextField *) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange) range replacementString: (NSString *) string
{
    NSString *result = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange: range withString: string];
    if ( [result intValue] < 0 || [result intValue] > 32 )
        return NO;
    return YES;
}
```

For consistency, you may also want to implement -textFieldShouldEndEditing: to return false when the value is invalid.

Comment: Cheers Costique. I'll check this later.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
[aTextfield.text intValue] < 32
```

to compare the text in the Textfield to 32. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Sandro. Would that actually restrict the user typing any value over 32?

Comment: No that's only to compare the value in the TextField. But you could show a message when he tries to end the editing... ;-)